# How to click through items in an array, in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a api that returns data that I want to cycle through. I have them in position absolute so the data is stacked on top of one another. On the click, I want to cycle through an array that is returned. I have looked up the documentation on React but it's not giving me viable answers. I think my logic is faulty and I don't know what to do. I am new to React. Can anyone help me out?

Here is my code:

class Members extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: null,
      senators: [],
      represenatives: [],
      bills: [],
      index: 0
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    })
  }

  right = (i) => {
   // this one to go backwards
  }
  left = (i) => {
   // this one is supposed to go forward
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const key = `xCaHBd8gI5ZJSOUXWFJGOXZBjJtMbvoIcip0kSmS`
    const urls = [`https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/116/senate/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/102/house/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/statements/latest.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/bills/search.json`];

    let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url, {
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'X-API-Key': key
      }
    }))
    Promise.all(requests)
      .then(res => {
        return Promise.all(res.map(res => res.json()));
      }).then(response => {
        this.setState({
          senators: response[0].results[0].members,
          represenatives: response[1].results[0].members,
          bills: response[2].results
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }

  render() {

    const { senators, bills, represenatives, userInput } = this.state;

    const inSenate = senators.filter(
      (senator) => senator.state === userInput
    )

    const inHouse = represenatives.filter(
      (represenative) => represenative.state === userInput
    )

    const draft = bills.find(
      (bill) => bill.name === inSenate.last_name)



    return (

      <div className="congress">
        <div className="users">
          <h2>{this.state.userInput}</h2>
          <input className="userInput" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>

        {inSenate.map((senate, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={senate.id} className="senate">
              <h2 className="senateName">Senate</h2>
              <ul className="bio">
                <h2 >{senate.short_title + " " + senate.first_name + " " + senate.last_name}</h2>
                <li>{senate.title}</li>
                <li>State: <strong>{senate.state}</strong></li>
                <li>Party: <strong>{senate.party}</strong></li>
                <li>DOB: <strong>{senate.date_of_birth}</strong></li>
                <li>Next Election: <strong>{senate.next_election}</strong></li>
                <li>Missed Votes: <strong>{senate.missed_votes}</strong></li>
                <li> Votes With Party Percentage: <strong>{senate.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                <li>Votes Against Party Percentage: <strong>{senate.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          )
        })}

        {inHouse.map((rep, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={rep.id} className="house">
              <h2 className="numbers" >Your state has {inHouse.length} Represenative(s)</h2>
              <h2 >{rep.short_title + " " + rep.first_name + " " + rep.last_name}</h2>
              <ul className="bio">
                <li  >{rep.title}</li>
                <li  >State: <strong>{rep.state}</strong></li>
                <li  >Party: <strong>{rep.party}</strong></li>
                <li  >DOB: <strong>{rep.date_of_birth}</strong></li>
                <li  >Next Election: <strong>{rep.next_election}</strong></li>
                <li  >Missed Votes: <strong>{rep.missed_votes}</strong></li>
                <li  > Votes With Party Percentage: <strong>{rep.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                <li  >Votes Against Party Percentage: <strong>{rep.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
              </ul>
              <button onClick={() => this.left(rep)} className="left btn"></button>
              <button onClick={() => this.right(rep)} className="right btn"></button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the index of the current item in the component's state and only render the current item. On click, call setState with an incremented index, which will trigger a re-render with the next item.

```
class Members extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentSenateIndex: 0,
    currentHouseIndex: 0
  }

  onSenateClick () {
    // you'd want to modulus this (%) to the length of the options
    // to have it loop back to 0 instead of running off the end of
    // the array; omitted here for simplicity
    this.setState({ currentSenateIndex: currentSenateIndex + 1 })
  }

  render () {
    const {currentSenateIndex, currentHouseIndex} = this.state;
    const senateItem = inSenate[currentSenateIndex];
    const houseItem = inHouse[currentHouseIndex];

    return (
      <div onClick={this.onSenateClick}> ...render senate stuff... </div>
    )
  }

}
```